# Get URL parameters from custom link in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I there a way to parse custom URL (not through the `$location` service, i.e. not the one the browser is currently pointing to) and extract/manipulate the URL attributes in Angular.js? I need this, in order to pass some links to a directive in side the controller, but first I have to construct them.

For example:

```
//test/query?e=1&page=10
```

And the requested output should be similar to this:

```
{ host: 'test', resource: 'query', search: { e: '1', page: '10' } }
```

Comment: Please be more specific as to what you want to do and using what data source. As it stands now it is not clear at all what you are asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/PT5BG/314/) maybe this is enough for you. Anchor gives you some functions for parsing given url. On the provided jsfiddle link you can test it.

```
function AppCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.$watch('url', function () {
        $scope.parser.href = $scope.url;
    });

    $scope.init = function () {
        $scope.parser = document.createElement('a');
        $scope.url = window.location;
    }

}
```